# Docker & Oracle Autonomous DB - TLS connection NOT working

Tags: python, database, oracle, docker, oracle-autonomous-db

Before starting to explain the issue, all the code I'm going to mention is also publicly available [in my repository](https://github.com/jasperan/forza-horizon-5-telemetry-listener).

I'm trying to connect to my autonomous database instance without a wallet, by disabling m-TLS and using TLS instead. I have properly configured it so that I can connect with only a username, password and DSN strings.

If I execute this code from my python environment, I can successfully see the result:

[image: img1]

However, when I execute this same exact code inside a Docker container, it fails for some reason.

[image: 2]

Saying failure to open file, which is weird I think, since I shouldn't be referencing any file having avoided mutual TLS as the authentication mechanism for the autonomous database.

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:21

#RUN dnf -y install oracle-instantclient-release-el8 && \
#    dnf -y install oracle-instantclient-basic oracle-instantclient-devel oracle-instantclient-sqlplus && \
#    rm -rf /var/cache/dnf

RUN yum -y update && yum install -y python3 python3-pip

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
# Wallet is no longer needed as we're using TLS to connect to ADB. See src/testing_db_tls.py for more info.
COPY wallet /home/appuser/wallets/Wallet_forza
# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser
EXPOSE 65530/udp

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
ENTRYPOINT "python3" "src/oracledb.py"
```

Note that this Dockerfile is also correct, executing the connection code inside the Docker container with a wallet and the corresponding code that references to the wallet location has always worked.

So my question is, does Docker have something that impedes connecting through TLS to a database that I'm missing or some other restricting parameter unallowing me to properly connect inside a Docker container? The executed code is exactly the same, and both in and outside of the Docker image I have Oracle's instant client.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've also tried with standard Docker images like ubuntu, python slim buster and alpine to no avail

Comment: Expose port 65530 with **udp** is expected or should this be tcp?

Comment: Assuming you're using Python cx_Oracle (hinted at in a screenshot), then note the current Oracle Client C libraries (19.13) don't support 1-way TLS, so you'll have to use mTLS and a wallet for the moment.

Comment: @gohm'c it's expected since Forza's telemetry uses UDP

Comment: @ChristopherJones yes I'm using Python cx_Oracle. Is there any ETA you know for this? Using wallets is the most boring part of databases... I'd implemented this since I read this article (https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/securely-connecting-to-autonomous-db-without-a-wallet-using-tls#Can%20I%20Enable%20both%20TLS%20and%20mTLS) which supports TLS in JDBC, figured it would be the same for cx_Oracle but now I guess not

Comment: Update to my previous comment: a recut 19.13 Instant Client for Linux x64 is available in the normal places. It does support 1-way TLS, as well adding support for Oracle IAM tokens.  The recut files end with '-2'; also the Basic & Basic Light READMEs mention the new features.

Comment: @ChristopherJones, is this recut also available in Windows? Any way I can check this out periodically without bothering you?

Comment: A future Windows Instant Client will have the features.  I'll update my [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/secure-adb-connections-wallet-less-one-way-tls-and-iam-tokens-in-oracle-instant-client-1913) or https://stackoverflow.com/users/16398167/sharad will create a more detailed post on the same site.

Comment: Note that a 1-way TLS on Linux requires CA certificates from the hard-coded(?) path /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem, which is not true for debian /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem or alpine /etc/ssl/cert.pem. A simple symbolic link solves this problem.